# Want to create tables based on the below requirement

Tags: database, oracle, data-modeling

1. Tables column details as follows :

   ```
   id - number,
   Description - varchar 2,
   partition_0_to_5 - varchar2,
   partition_6_to_10 - varchar2,
   partition_11_to_15 - varchar2,
   status - varcha2
   ```

But values in partition_0_to_5 , partition_6_to_10 , and partition_11_to_15 is coming from one master table and can have more than one values. Suppose say id number 1 belongs to two partitions i.e 1. Build and 6. C then these values should go in partition_0_to_5 and partition_6_to_10 columns.

2. Master table for Partition stages contains id and task column.

> 0. start
> 1. Build
> 2. Test
> 3. Reg Test
> 4. A
> 5. B
> 6. C
> 7. D
> 8. E
> 9. F
> 10. G
> 11. H
> 12. I
> 13. J
> 14. K
> 15. L

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, that's a wrong data model. You should normalize it for future sake because - what will you do when new partition is created (16 - 20)? Alter table? Modify **all** code you've already written to include a new partition? Good luck with that!

(Besides, your question isn't about *modelling*, it is to be "solved" during insert, i.e. in application code - not data model. Which is - as I said - wrong, in my opinion).

---

Here's my suggestion; think about it.

This is the "main" table; in your current model, it contains 3 additional columns (partitions):

```
SQL> create table table_1
  2    (id_tab      number primary key,
  3     description varchar2(20),
  4     status      varchar2(2)
  5    );

Table created.
```

List of partitions. If new partition is created (16 - 20), you'd just insert a new row into this table - no code should be changed, nor any table altered.

```
SQL> create table part
  2    (id_part     number primary key,
  3     description varchar2(20)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into part (id_part, description)
  2    select 1, ' 0 -  5' from dual union all
  3    select 2, ' 6 - 10' from dual union all
  4    select 3, '11 - 15' from dual;

3 rows created.
```

Partition stages:

```
SQL> create table part_stage
  2    (id_part_stage number primary key,
  3     id_part       number references part (id_part),
  4     task          varchar2(20)
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into part_stage (id_part_stage, id_part, task)
  2    select  0, 1, 'start'    from dual union all
  3    select  1, 1, 'build'    from dual union all
  4    select  2, 1, 'test'     from dual union all
  5    select  3, 1, 'reg test' from dual union all
  6    select  4, 1, 'A'        from dual union all
  7    select  5, 1, 'B'        from dual union all
  8    select  6, 2, 'C'        from dual union all
  9    select  7, 2, 'D'        from dual union all
 10    select  8, 2, 'E'        from dual union all
 11    select  9, 2, 'F'        from dual union all
 12    select 10, 2, 'G'        from dual union all
 13    select 11, 3, 'H'        from dual union all
 14    select 12, 3, 'I'        from dual union all
 15    select 13, 3, 'J'        from dual union all
 16    select 14, 3, 'K'        from dual union all
 17    select 15, 3, 'L'        from dual;

16 rows created.
```

This table is used to "map" the main table (`table_1`) to partition stages (`part_stage`). Doing so, it is flexible so you can add as many partition stages for each main record as you want. If new partition is created, no problem either - it is (again) just another row in the `tmap` table.

```
SQL> create table tmap
  2    (id_map        number primary key,
  3     id_tab        number references table_1 (id_tab),
  4     id_part_stage number references part_stage (id_part_stage)
  5    );

Table created.
```

Sequence (for primary keys):

```
SQL> create sequence seqmap;

Sequence created.
```

How would insert look like?

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_id_tab number := seqmap.nextval;
  3  begin
  4    -- parent record
  5    insert into table_1 (id_tab, description, status)
  6      values (l_id_tab, 'Test insert', 'A1');
  7
  8    -- child record (build)
  9    insert into tmap (id_map, id_tab, id_part_stage)
 10      values (seqmap.nextval, l_id_tab, 1);
 11
 12    -- child record (C)
 13    insert into tmap (id_map, id_tab, id_part_stage)
 14      values (seqmap.nextval, l_id_tab, 6);
 15  end;
 16  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

What's being inserted?

```
SQL> select * from table_1;

    ID_TAB DESCRIPTION          ST
---------- -------------------- --
         1 Test insert          A1

SQL> select * from tmap;

    ID_MAP     ID_TAB ID_PART_STAGE
---------- ---------- -------------
         2          1             1
         3          1             6
```

"Report" which shows what belongs to what:

```
SQL> select a.id_tab, a.description, a.status, p.description, ps.task
  2  from table_1 a join tmap  t on t.id_tab = a.id_tab
  3                 join part_stage ps on ps.id_part_stage = t.id_part_stage
  4                 join part p on p.id_part = ps.id_part
  5  where a.id_tab = 1;

    ID_TAB DESCRIPTION          ST DESCRIPTION          TASK
---------- -------------------- -- -------------------- --------------------
         1 Test insert          A1  0 -  5              build
         1 Test insert          A1  6 - 10              C

SQL>
```

---

What happens when new partition is created? Nothing, just a few inserts:

```
SQL> insert into part (id_part, description)
  2    select 4, '16 - 20' from dual;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into part_stage (id_part_stage, id_part, task)
  2    select 16, 4, 'M' from dual union all
  3    select 17, 4, 'N' from dual union all
  4    select 18, 4, 'O' from dual union all
  5    select 19, 4, 'P' from dual union all
  6    select 20, 4, 'Q' from dual;

5 rows created.
```

Add a new partition stage to existing `table_1` record:

```
SQL> insert into tmap (id_map, id_tab, id_part_stage)
  2    values (seqmap.nextval, 1, 20);

1 row created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select a.id_tab, a.description, a.status, p.description, ps.task
  2  from table_1 a join tmap  t on t.id_tab = a.id_tab
  3                 join part_stage ps on ps.id_part_stage = t.id_part_stage
  4                 join part p on p.id_part = ps.id_part
  5  where a.id_tab = 1;

    ID_TAB DESCRIPTION          ST DESCRIPTION          TASK
---------- -------------------- -- -------------------- --------------------
         1 Test insert          A1  0 -  5              build
         1 Test insert          A1  6 - 10              C
         1 Test insert          A1 16 - 20              Q

SQL>
```

See? I didn't change any piece of code, altered any table ... nothing. Everything just *works*. In your data model, you'd have a lot more job to do.

Once again, consider doing it this way. *Proper* way, in my opinion.